# Sublime text select line without start tabs/spaces and end of string

Tags: sublimetext

As you know, you can select line under cursor with hot key ctrl + L (linux ubuntu). But selected text include start spaces or tabs and \n at the end.
[image] How can I select line without spaces or tabs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save the following `sublime-macro` to:
`Packages/MyMacroFolder/Select LineText.sublime-macro`

```
[
    {
        "command": "move_to",
        "args": { "extend": false, "to": "eol" }
    },
    {
        "command": "move_to",
        "args": { "extend": true, "to": "bol" }
    }
]
```

---

Open your user `sublime-keymap` file by running `Preferences: Key Bindings - User` from the `command palette`.

Add a `key-binding` for `Select LineText.sublime-macro`.

```
{
    "keys": [ "ctrl+shift+alt+l" ],
    "command": "run_macro_file",
    "args": { "file": "res://Packages/MyMacroFolder/Select LineText.sublime-macro" },
},
```

---

You will now be able to select line text ( *excluding leading & trailing whitespace* ) with whatever key-binding you assigned in your `sublime-keymap`.

The key-binding in the example is <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Alt + L</kbd>

Comment: Is posible to select multiple lines with the same behavior like ctrl+l do? thanks.

Comment: @JorgeOlivares:  You can add most SublimeText & plugin commands to macro files. Just add another dictionary with `"command": "split_selection_into_lines"` at the beginning (*no args*).  You can also run the following script in the console in order to see the commands & arguments from any of your key bindings: `sublime.log_commands(True); sublime.log_input(True); sublime.active_window().run_command("show_panel", {"panel": "console"});`